# BitmapData allocates a lot of memory when created

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

I have an application which manipulates high resolution images (something around 100+ megapixels), and I'm having some memory issues. When the BitmapData object is created, it allocates memory to store this image. The problem, is that I already have a ByteArray with this image's pixels (which have something around 400+ MB), so when the BitmapData is created, it allocates memory to store the same data that I have on the ByteArray.

After its creation, I can set the pixels from the ByteArray to the BitmapData and free the ByteArray. But this memory peak is, sometimes, causing the runtime to raise an exception, telling that the system is out of memory.

Is there any way to tell the BitmapData to use my own ByteArray? Or any other solution that I don't have to use double the memory that I need?

Comment: @AstheWormTurns that's a pretty great resource right there, very in depth look at memory consumption with BitmapData, I may need to re-read that one a couple of times to make sure I remember how exactly that's actually working.

Comment: @Tiago I assume you're using setPixels on the BitmapData to load the info from the byte array into the bitmapData?  If you don't find any other solution perhaps you can load the image piecewise, meaning pull the first 1/4 of the image into memory (or the whole thing then chunk it up) then call setPixels 4 times and during each free the memory in the original byte array as soon as it's been set on the bitmapData... (quarters is just an example might work better with more or less division I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone needs this, here's what I did:

I get the ByteArray, which contains the pixels of the image, from a socket. I read these pixels from the sockets in tiny parts, so I, instead of waiting for the whole image to be loaded from the socket, I put these small parts directly into the BitmapData. This prevents the application to allocate double the memory I actually need.